# Is this resistor sufficient as dummy load in an ATX 250W Dell PSU?

Tags: power-supply, resistors, ac, dc, atx

I have attached a 20 Ohm resistor to my Dell PSU on the 5V rail since its a 2004 PSU and most of the current is on the +3.3V & +5V rail. I have seen on most youtube videos where they mention using such dummy loads but they are usually those ceramic resistors. I dont a have 10 or 20 ohm 5W one in my posession now. But I do have a 1 ohm 5W resistance which I assume isn't ideal. Just attached this resistor I had previously salvaged from an old Nokia charger. I have attached a picture below for better idea.Thanks in advance everyone.
[image: IMG 1]

[image: IMG 2]

Comment: If I am not mistaken such power supplies should have enough internal load to make PSU start. You should not need external load (unless practice shows otherwise). And I think 1 Ohm resistor will just fry quickly as for 3.3 V there will be 3.3 A current and thus 10 W, for 5V there will be 5 A and 25 W. Edit: your resistor looks like 10 Ohm, not 1 Ohm?

Comment: @Anonymous the resistor shown in above pic connected to the supply is a 10 Ohm resistor. I was saying that I have only a 1 ohm 5W rectangular ceramic resistor. Most ATX-Bench supply videos I have seen they use those ceramic resistors for loads. I added a dummy load resistor because I have in many videos and websites people mention that without a dummy load the ATX output will be unstable.

Comment: Your average 12 V 1 W fan on the 5 V rail usually cuts ut, but your milage may vary. Aim for 100 mA and report back on your findings.

Comment: @winny currently the dummy load (10 ohm) is connected to the 5V. So, I'm drawing around 250mA.

Comment: Look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply_unit_(computer)#Testing. If you want to do testing things properly it is not just as easy as connect resistor. What is the purpose of you connecting "dummy" load?

Comment: I know ATX supplies are complex and dangerous if not handled properly. Was just looking for an easy way out. I was planning on a temporary solution like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QoGnOoTICGY

Comment: Did 250 mA work? Can you go lower?

Comment: okay. So I've added another 20 ohm in parallel. Heating of the resistor is definetiley there but the output is kinda stable I hope.